# Using the compare method to compare multiple words to an external file

Tags: java, string, algorithm, search, if-statement

I have a program that takes input from 1 file, saves each word from that file as an item in an arrayList, and then searches for each word in another file. From there I need it to see if a word from another string is in the same line as as the words searched for. The logic is a bit confusing so I will give you an example:

This is the input from the first file:

```
Tuna, Salmon, Hake.
```

It then saves each item into an arrayList:

```
{Tuna,Salmon,Hake}
```

From there it will search a file with the following data:

```
It costs $5 for tuna that is seared and chunky.
We are out of stock on hake.
It costs $6 for sardines that are tinned.
It costs $4 for tuna that is seared.
```

So then program would then search the above file and see that tuna is in the 1st and 4th lines and that hake is in the 2nd line, and that salmon does not appear.

From here I want to have a list of words for example:

```
Seared, chunky, out of stock.
```

And compare this list to see if they are in the same line as the other words so that it prints out:

```
Tuna is seared and chunky
Hake is out of stock
Tuna is seared
```

So far I have code that works perfectly, but it only works for 1 word. An example of my code is below:

```
while((strLine1 = br1.readLine()) != null){
            for(String list: listOfWords){
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(list);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine1);

    String strLine2 = "seared" ;      

        int start = 0;
        while (m.find(start)) {
            System.out.printf("Word found: %s at index %d to %d.%n", m.group(), m.start(), m.end());
            if(strLine1.contains(strLine2)){
               System.out.println(list + " is " + strLine2);
                        }
            start = m.end();
                }    
            }
          }
```

So what this code will print out is:

```
Tuna is seared (referring to line 1)
Tuna is seared (referring to line 4)
```

I think in order to achieve this, I could use **and or** in my if statement or try an arrayList for strLine2, but for the latter, the contains method cannot compare a string to an arrayList.

Let me know if my explanation is confusing or if you have any ideas as to how I can achieve my goals. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working with an arrayList and an advanced for loop.

```
String[] strLine2 = {"seared","chunky","out of stock"} ;      

        int start = 0;
        while (m.find(start)) {
            System.out.printf("Word found: %s at index %d to %d.%n", m.group(), m.start(), m.end());
            for(String lineWords: strLine2){
            if(strLine1.contains(lineWords)){
               System.out.println(list + " is " + lineWords);
                        }
            }
            start = m.end();

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure but I thought yo want to find all words that are in your list..
and in this line

```
if(strLine1.contains(strLine2)){
```

you always check if "seared" is in the actual line could it be, that you have to change this line and search for the word of your list?

```
if(strLine1.contains(list)){
```

So now you get all your words.

Comment: as it is, the code gets the all the data from the first file and searches for it in the second file and returns the location of every word. I want to check for more words than the word seared. {Seared, chucky and out of stock}. But you have given me an idea that uses a for loop.

Comment: ahhh ok.. so you go through a loop with all the elements you found?

Comment: just got my program to work with an arrayList and an advanced for loop. But thanks for the help

Comment: posted an answer showing what I did. but ya, that's basically all I needed to do